# Django App not connecting to RDS since SSL/TLS Cert Updates

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I have a Django app running on ELB connecting to a MySQL RDS db.

I checked recently and its no longer working (application is up fine but I get the following error when I try and deploy or run any manage.py db related commands. I can connect to the RDS DB manually without a problem.

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '****.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (110)").
```

I believe this is to do with the recent updates to SSL/TLS certificates - however I've gone into my RDS dashboard and updated to the new 2019 version there and I'm still getting this error.

Does anyone know what might be causing this? It worked fine before the cert change so I can only assume it's related.

I've tried adding the ssl-ca `rds-ca-2019-root.pem` to the DB options in django but still get the same error regardless.

Any help would be super appreciated as I'm pretty stumped currently.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using TLS for your DB connections, I've had the most success using the "combined" ca bundle that AWS provides.

The file can be found here https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem which is referenced in the [Using SSL/TLS to Encrypt a Connection to a DB Instance guide.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html). It would be good to also review this guide to sanity check any of your other assumptions.

Comment: I managed to deploy after changing the security group on my RDS to allow all incoming connections for the moment - however although I don't get any errors none of my queries seem to actually do anything.